Are there rpc calls to show the size / transaction types in the mempool?
Are there rpc calls to show the size / transaction types in the mempool?
I've never seen any visualisation of the mempool for polkadot or substrate chains.
Other chains seem to have visibility into their mempools. Or is there some polkadot-js corner that I have not yet visited?

Under polkadot-js, node info, there's a 'Pending Extrinsics' area. E.g.
https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fentrypoint-finney.opentensor.ai%3A443#/explorer/node
Presumably given that substrate is so efficient in general most of the time this seems empty as the transactions all fit in the block.

Please mark it as the answer if this resolves your question.
